# Devise's current_user nil in ApplicationController but not in a different controller (using Simple Token Authentication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have a Rails 3.2.22 app running in production for +1 year which uses Devise to authenticate users.

I'm trying to implement token authentication, so I can send transactional e-mails with URL params that can log in the user automatically, using a Gem named Simple Token Authentication https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication

After following all the instructions, I replaced `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in my controllers with `acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User`.

The gem has integration with and a **default** fallback to Devise, so devise doesn't need to be called in the controllers anymore; if the token is missing from the params (or wrong), Devise will take over.

In my tests, if I add this line to `ApplicationController`, everything works fine and I can log in users using the `authentication_token=` secret the gem generates.

But I don't need `auth` for ApplicationController, I need it for other controllers (like DashboardController), url being /dashboard

If I put `acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User` in that controller (replacing Devise's call), I get the most bizarre of situations.

Using binding.pry, I can confirm that `current_user` is correctly set during the loading of the template.

But there comes a point in the template where it uses @last_emails, which is defined inside a method in `ApplicationController`.

Using binding.pry, I can confirm `current_user` is *nil* there.

This is the code:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  layout 'material'

  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User
```

And in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 layout 'omega'

 before_filter :populate_last_contacts_for_menu 

private
  def populate_last_contacts_for_menu
    if current_user
      @last_contacts = Contact.where("user_id" => current_user.id).where('blocked != ? or blocked is null', true).last(10).reverse
    end
  end
```

Funny thing is: using binding.pry, like I said, I can check that current_user is defined in the template (which means sign_in was a success). It even is defined  in the better errors console. But, if I go to homepage, I see that user is not logged in ...

I've looked all over the web for this: read all the issues inside the Gem's github and all posts in SO about current_user being nil, but no light at all.

My `devise_for :users` is not inside any scope in routes.rb and, as I said, I have many calls to current_user all over the app and this is the first time I have issues with Devise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for` directive in the `DashboardController` it declares some `before_filters` for the controller to authenticate a user.

But the problem is that when you inherit rails controllers, at first, filters of a parent controller are executed, then filters of a child controller.

The parent controller is `ApplicationController`. At the moment when it's `populate_last_contacts_for_menu` filter is called, the user is not authentacated, because the authenticating filters given by the `acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for` directive have not called yet, they are declared in the child controller.

**Possible solutions:**

1) Try to append the `populate_last_contacts_for_menu` filter:

```
append_before_filter :populate_last_contacts_for_menu
```

I am not sure it will work in your case, but you can try and find it out.

2) Call the `acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for` directive in the `ApplicationControoler` and somehow skip it for the controllers that don't need it. (I don't like this way, but it may help if the first one will not work. )

3) Move the `populate_last_contacts_for_menu` filter logic into helpers. I think it is the best solution. This logic doesn't belong to a controller. When requests are not 'get', this filter executes for nothing, because you don't need to render views in that case.

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def last_contacts
    @last_contacts ||= if signed_in?
      Contact.where("user_id" => current_user.id).where('blocked != ? or blocked is null', true).last(10).reverse
    else
      []
    end
  end
  ...
end

# View:

<% if last_contacts.present? %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

Comment: even tough I understood your explanation, could you explain why the same issue didn't happen with Devise, since I just replaced `before_filter: authenticate_user!` to the new auth method, in the same controller that also inherits from ApplicationController ? Also, your solution of moving `populate_last_contacts_for_menu` to a helper worked, but I was avoiding changing any of the app's logic for this. The reason is a simple one: if I'm only changing the authentication method from Devise to a Gem that integrates and extends Devise, why any line of could should be rewritten ?

Comment: the devise's `current_user` method doesn't require the `auhenticate_user!` filter to be executed every request. Once the `authenticate_user!` method is called, it sets current user id in the session and on the next request the 'current_user' method returns the current user even if the  `authenticate_user!` method are not called. It seems to be that the Simple Token Authentication gem has different behaviour. It's before filters are needed for setting the current_user as well as for authenticating, while the devise's `authenticate_user!` filter and the `current_user` method work independently.